# Downcasting an unsigned long into a method that requires an int in C++ in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, downcast

I am trying to pass a variable to a method that takes an int argument. My variable, however, is an unsigned long. The code looks something like this:

```
unsigned long uLongNum = veryBigNumber;
int x = smallInteger; // usually between two and eight
myObject->myMethod(int y);
```

What I am passing (many times) looks like this:

```
myMethod(uLongNum / (ULongMax / x));
```

The purpose is to divide a large array of big integers into two new arrays based on the number's size. My code is only generating zeros and not ones and zeros into myObject (I can generate ones with this code in VS2012).

Note: I asked a similar question a couple of days ago but my question was a bit ambiguous. I hope this clears up the ambiguity. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know that you could get wrong values because of your cast?

Comment: Yes. I am wondering how to downcast that long into the int argument.

Comment: Without the wrong-value-possibility, you can´t. Adapt the method to work with `unsigned long`. (that means not only a change of formal parameter, but the whole method/class/whatever)

Comment: The method returns `void` so I'm not sure how you're planning on achieving "expecting the method to return a one or zero". If all you care about is sending either a 1 or 0 for the `y` parameter, then something like `(uLongNum >= (ULongMax / x))` would seem to fit.

Comment: (lol, I didn´t even looked at the code itself)

Comment: @WhozCraig, that's just poor semantics on my part. The method is really changing the value of an object (I know, what object?). I'll make it look more semantically correct.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> unsigned long uLongNum = veryBigNumber;
> int x = smallInteger; // usually between two and eight
> void myMethod(int y);
> ```

And from your comment:

> ... I am wondering how to downcast that long into the int argument.

Perhaps something like:

```
unsigned long uLongNum = veryBigNumber;
if(uLongNum > std::numeric_limits<int>::max())
    throw std::out_of_range();

int x = static_cast<int>(veryBigNumber);
myMethod(x);
...
```